# c3.js chart data is loaded but graph does not render while page load and refresh

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, django-templates, c3.js

I tried some examples of **c3.js** [Followed this link](http://c3js.org/). And i got success in that. But i have one problem when i'm trying to load graph first time in any browser, it doesn't show me the graph.

And if i reload page once or twice it shows graph but data is loaded.
I'm using latest **version 0.6.1** library in my project, even though chart not shown.

I googled quite a lot but i couldn't found any correct solution. 
If anything is there to fix this issue suggest me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you found a solution? (I have the same problem)

Comment: @irene  Still didn't find correct solution but i managed that problem by reducing the data load.Usually this problem occurs when we load the large amount of data into the c3 chart.